# Creating new elements and attaching them to a parent element via a join table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, join

I'm migrating a database model where I have to change a `1:n` relation to a `n:m` relation.

I need to `INSERT` the data into the new table and use the `ID` that is generated in the process to fill the join table.

The tables are called `Parts` and `Document` and the join table between them called `PartDocument`.

Now I want to create two unique `documents` (with default types/names/descriptions) for each `part`, and link them to the corresponding `part` via the join table. I can create the 2*N `documents` easily, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how I would link each one to the `PartDocument` join table.

```
INSERT INTO Document (Type, Name, Description)
SELECT 1, 'Work Instructions', 'Work Instructions'
FROM Parts
GO

INSERT INTO Document (Type, Name, Description)
SELECT 2, 'Drawing', 'Drawing'
FROM Parts
GO

INSERT INTO PartDocument (PartID, DocumentID)
?????
```

My `PartDocument` join table just has two columns, `PartID` and `DocumentID`, which are used together as a composite key.

My desired result is that I will have two documents for each part, and they will each be linked with a corresponding part via the join table.

I'm using SQL Server Express 2012.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b51f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a temporary PartID column when I created the Document table. Then I could drop this column after I created and linked the Documents.

So basically this:

```
INSERT INTO Document (Type, Name, Description, PartID)
SELECT 1, 'Work Instructions', 'Work Instructions', Part.ID
FROM Part
GO

INSERT INTO PartDocument
SELECT Document.PartID, Document.ID
FROM Document
GO

ALTER TABLE Document
DROP COLUMN PartID
GO
```

Comment: you should mark the answer as correct (with the hook below the numbers).

Comment: @Angelo Neuschitzer It makes me wait to answer my own question and then longer to accept. XD Thanks for the help btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Document (Type, Name, Description)
SELECT 1, 'Work Instructions', 'Work Instructions'
FROM Parts
GO

INSERT INTO Document (Type, Name, Description)
SELECT 2, 'Drawing', 'Drawing'
FROM Parts
GO

INSERT INTO PartDocument (PartID, DocumentID)
SELECT part.id, document.id
FROM Parts part
INNER JOIN Document document ON part.field1 = document.field1
GO
```

The complex element is the `ON` part in the `INNER JOIN` in the last selection. You have to select the lines that you have just created together with the parts elements that they came from.

Comment: The INSERT SELECT is creating 1 document for every part. So after I run both inserts, I have twice as many documents total as parts. The document IDs are autogenerated, and I don't know the PartIDs. They're being drawn from the database.

I don't think this is quite doing what I'm looking for. xD

Comment: @hashtable If you want that, than you should not have a cross join table. It would be better to have the PartID in your document. (Or can a document be connected to more than one Part?)

Comment: Documents can be connected to more than one part in the new version of the database. (In the old version, it couldn't). This is part of my script to reformat and migrate the old data to the new database model. After I get these linked, I'm going to be creating DocumentVersions that point to these "Document" placeholders. So yes, I want a join table. xD

Comment: @hashtable Okay, so you will have to use more complex and database specific solutions (like triggers, updateable views or similar). What Database are you using and is it possible to use a programming language here (and which one?)

Comment: @hashtable Also, I changed my answer to a new approach that might work, but for that I would need more data about your setting. Have you considered setting up a SQLFiddle to demonstrate it?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Express, and I was hoping to accomplish the task in the database update script where I make the changes to the ORM. xD But it is seeming difficult to do.

Comment: Resolved the problem. :D Can't post the answer for 3 hours though. >-<